# Why are the TypeScript compilerOptions 'noEmitOnError: true' and 'isolatedModules: false' not compatible?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, compiler-options

When I run TypeScript with `isolatedModules` true and `isolatedModules` false, I get this error:

```
tsconfig.json(5,9): error TS5053: Option 'noEmitOnError' cannot be specified with option 'isolatedModules'.
```

Why??

Example tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
    }
}
```

Comment: opened an issue on the TS repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the restriction was a mistake.
Fixed on master!: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31043